# strange javascript form behaviour

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am generating the following html form with this php:

```
echo "<form name=\"userForm\">
Username:
<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" />
<br />
First name:
<input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\" />
<br />
Last name:
<input type=\"text\" name=\"lastname\" />
<br />
<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" onclick=\"submitUserInfo();return false\"/>
</form>";
```

Which is handled by submitUserInfo, which is here:

```
function submitUserInfo() {
    url = "edit_user.php?cmd=submitinfo&username="+document.userForm.username.value+"&firstname="+document.userForm.firstname.value+"&lastname="+document.userForm.lastname.value;
    var xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if(xmlHttp.responseText == 'true') {
        alert(url);
        xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        //updateByUser(username);
    }
}
```

I clearly have url defined as beginning with

```
edit_user.php?cmd=submitinfo&username
```

however when pressing the submit button, it tries to send the url as

```
edit_user.php?username=
```

and I cannot figure out why. I have used the above technique succusfully with other forms on my site, and can not find any reason that cmd=submitinfo& is being excluded.

Comment: What's the GetXmlHttpObject implementation ? What's that check on responseText == 'true' ? What happens if you try to make url local (var url = "...";) ? What happens if you display the url just after you build it ? what happens if you display it just after the call to GetXmlHttpObject ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tool like Firebug to determine if the browser is sending it without cmd=submitinfo& or if it's being lost on the server side.

Comment: Wouldn't displaying the url be just as useful to see if I am sending it clientside or not?

Comment: Displaying it where?  You need to start at the root of the problem and seeing if it's making it through the first place it's sent -- from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
url = "edit_user.php?cmd=submitinfo&username="+document.userForm.username.value+"&firstname="+document.userForm.firstname.value+"&lastname="+document.userForm.lastname.value;
```

to:

```
var url = "edit_user.php?cmd=submitinfo&username="+document.userForm.username.value+"&firstname="+document.userForm.firstname.value+"&lastname="+document.userForm.lastname.value;
```

You must declare your `url` variable before you try to use it.

Also, avoid `echo`ing straight HTML to the page.  The way you've done it is going to be an absolute pain to debug, update, and stylize.

Comment: what is the preferred method to comment html?

Comment: The preferred method is not to comment it at all, but put the HTML on the page itself

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is not really needed for such simple tasks, although I would suggest you taking a look if you plan to implement more JavaScript on your site.

Your code, using jQuery, would look like this:

```
$("#<id of form goes here>").submit(function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            "username": $("#<id of username-input goes here>").val(),
            "firstname": $("#<id of firstname-input goes here>").val(),
            "lastname": $("#<id of lastname-input goes here>").val()
        },

        url: "edit_user.php"
    });

    return false;
});
```

Looks a bit nicer, I think :)

Also; using frameworks - not jQuery in particular - takes care of browser work-arounds.. so you won't have to.. take care of 'em, that is :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the type of the button from "submit" to "button":

```
<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"button\" value=\"Update\" onclick=\"submitUserInfo();return false\"/>
```